# Как прочитать огромный JSON файл в Java?

Tags: java, json, eclipse

С сайта [безопасныедороги.рф](https://%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/open-data/crashes) необходимо из открытых данных в виде *JSON* вытащить информацию о геолокациях каждого дтп: `em_place_latitude` и `em_place_longitude`. Сам файл весит 1Гб и просто когда подключаешь файл - то выскакивает ошибка

> GC overhead limit exceeded

Я работал с библиотекой *simple-json* в *Eclipse*.

Так как я только начал знакомство с *JSON*, то вообще не понимаю как вытаскивать оттуда информацию, тем более из огромного файла.

Спасибо!

Comment: Вам должна помочь библиотека [`gson`](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле всё достаточно просто, если не загружать всё содержимое документа в память. Нужно, в принципе, помнить два основных подхода в разборе документов различных форматов: читается всё с помощью потока (`InputStream`/`Reader` или их аналоги) и решается как будет обрабатываться его содержимое: или собиранием всего в память (аналог XML DOM, когда документ, будучи полностью в памяти, позволяет с лёгкостью обходить его дерево), или же работать согласно событийной модели (аналог XML SAX или его pull-аналоги, когда парсер сообщает о том, какие токены встречаются в документе, а пользователь уже сам решает что и как с ними делать). Очевидно, что первый вариант проще в использовании, но требует куда больше ресурсов, в то время как второй вариант сложнее, но и более гибок, зачастую требуя вообще минимум ресурсов.

Gson позволяет работать с JSON-потоками с помощью pull-метода: это когда парсер не генерирует события, а предполагает, что пользователь сам знает, что и в каком порядке нужно "тянуть" с потока токенов, но и требуя чтобы *каждый* токен был обработан хоть как-то. Например:

```java
private static final String ITEMS_NAME = "items";
// em_place_latitude не описан в схеме и не встречается в документе
private static final String LATITUDE_PROPERTY = "latitude";
// em_place_longitude не описан в схеме и не встречается в документе
private static final String LONGITUDE_PROPERTY = "longitude";

static void parseCrashCoordinates(final JsonReader jsonReader, final ICoordinatesListener listener)
        throws IOException {
    // Считываем { как начало объекта.
    // Если его не считать или считать неверно, выбросится исключение -- это и есть суть pull-метода.
    jsonReader.beginObject();
    // Смотрим имя следующего свойства объекта и сравниваем его с ожидаемым.
    final String itemsName = jsonReader.nextName();
    if ( !itemsName.equals(ITEMS_NAME) ) {
        // Не items? Возможно, у нас нет идей как его обработать -- лучше выбросить исключение.
        throw new MalformedJsonException(ITEMS_NAME + " expected but was " + itemsName);
    }
    // Так же теперь вычитываем [
    jsonReader.beginArray();
    // И читаем каждый элемент массива
    while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
        // Судя по схеме, каждый элемент массива - объект
        jsonReader.beginObject();
        double latitude = 0;
        double longitude = 0;
        // И так же пробегаемся по всех свойствах этого объекта
        while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
            // Теперь просто смотрим, являются ли они нам известными
            final String property = jsonReader.nextName();
            switch ( property ) {
            // latitude? Запоминаем.
            case LATITUDE_PROPERTY:
                latitude = jsonReader.nextDouble();
                break;
            // longitude? Запоминаем.
            case LONGITUDE_PROPERTY:
                longitude = jsonReader.nextDouble();
                break;
            // Иначе просто пропускаем любое значение свойства.
            default:
                jsonReader.skipValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        // Просто делегируем полученные координаты в обработчик
        listener.onCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
        // И говорим, что с текущим элементом массива, именно объектом, покончено.
        jsonReader.endObject();
    }
    // Также закрываем последние ] и }
    jsonReader.endArray();
    jsonReader.endObject();
}
```

Как выглядит обработчик:

```java
interface ICoordinatesListener {

    void onCoordinates(double latitude, double longitude);

}
```

В принципе, возможны ситуации, когда в документе в координатах указана или широта или долгота, или оба значения отсутствуют (и, в принципе, обработка таких случаев является хорошим тоном), но при обработке `148817911056482-crash.json` мне такие случаи не встречались.

Теперь протестируем всё это дело.

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    testOutput();
    testCollecting();
}

// Этот тест просто выводит содержимое координат в стандартный поток вывода
// Заметьте: parseCrashCoordinates() сам не решает _что_ делать с координатами -- это целиком наше дело
// Поскольку мы вообще просто передаём данные дальше, нас вообще не волнует размер входных данных
// Теоретически, это может быть бесконечный поток данных -- круто ведь?
private static void testOutput()
        throws IOException {
    readAndParse((lat, lng) -> System.out.println("(" + lat + "; " + lng + ")"));
}

// Здесь мы, напротив, собираем координаты в список.
// Выдержит ли JVM увеличение списка coordinates? Возможно, но не факт: зависит от размера данных и памяти, доступной JVM.
private static void testCollecting()
        throws IOException {
    final List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    readAndParse((lat, lng) -> coordinates.add(new Coordinate(lat, lng)));
    System.out.println(coordinates.size());
}

private static final class Coordinate {

    private final double latitude;
    private final double longitude;

    private Coordinate(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}

private static void readAndParse(final ICoordinatesListener listener)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...)))) ) {
        parseCrashCoordinates(jsonReader, listener);
    }
}
```

Этим примером мне удалось разобрать `148817911056482-crash.json` размером 746 МБ, не особо тратясь на вычислительные ресурсы (громко сказано, тем не менее :)). Хвост вывода таков:

> (55.632584; 37.80792)
>   (51.5703; 135.8539)
>   (51.9139; 39.2233)
>   99497

(3 последние координаты и размер списка, в который были собраны все координаты).

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь! Я начал гуглить и самостоятельно пропарсил файл с помощью библиотеки *jackson*, но у меня ничего хорошего не вышло. На сколько я понял создается *arraylist* с координатами и уже можно с ними делать все, что заблагорассудится?

Comment: @Turtality Почти. Смысл обработки больших входных документов состоит в том, что их часто можно читать порциями и обрабатывать только нужные части. То есть, вы пишете "логический" парсер (поскольку Gson уже сам по себе предоставляет физический парсер: `JsonParser`), в котором вы просто описываете последовательность обработки входных токенов на более высоком уровне. Посмотрите как устроен `parseCrashCoordinates`. И, как только у вас есть достаточно информации о координате, в данном случае, вы просто через слушатель сигнализируете _кому-то_: "ой, смотри, ещё одна координата".

Comment: @Turtality А как уже устроен ваш слушатель -- это уже чисто ваша забота. Хотите -- собираете в список (если памяти достаточно); хотите -- просто выводите в файл или консоль; хотите -- вообще генерируете потоковое видео (а почему бы и нет? :) ); а хотите -- просто ничего не делаете. В этом кроется весь смысл.

Comment: А есть ли возможность в методе `parseCrashCoordinates` считывать координаты определенных аварий? Вот я пробовал туда операторы ветвления добавлять, но ничего хорошего не вышло. Потом придумал создать отдельный список с именами этих аварий (они там вылезают под этим именем `em_type_name`). Я создал в существующем интерфейсе новый метод `void onName(String name);` но после этого выдается ошибка, что метод `readAndParse` должен стать таким - `private static void readAndParse(Object listener) {}`

Comment: Вот это пишет в консоли - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method readAndParse(ICoordinatesListener) in the type JsonTest is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> lat, <no type> lng) -> {})
 The target type of this expression must be a functional interface`

Comment: А все я понял! Ваш код просто сказочно шикарный. Я перечитал сто раз ваши комментарии и врубился. В общем я добавил в блок `switch` этот код: `case CRASH_NAME:
              name = jsonReader.nextString();
              break; `  А после добавил такое условие:                        `if (name.contains("Наезд на пешехода")) {
          listener.onCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
         }` И теперь у меня в список собираются только нужные мне координаты. Спасибо огромное за помощь! Теперь буду думать как реализовать алгоритм k-means что бы собрать эти данные в кластеры. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Turtality Рад, что смог вам помочь, и удачи вам в решениях следующих проблем! :)