# Как парсить огромный JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp

Имеется огромный (22к строк) JSON с продуктами, полученный из API через OkHttpClient.
Его нужно распарсить для получения выборки вида:
Хлеб ржаной | 20шт | 245гр | упаковано 07.20 | и еще что-нибудь (| - это для удобства чтения, в выборке его не будет)

Беда в том, что в JSON-е прилетает еще горища ненужной инфы и она не сгруппирована по порядку. Показать нормальный фрагмент не выйдет т.к. редактор вываливает все в строку, поэтому придется скрины крепить. Если совсем не понятно, прилеплю кусок из самогО JSON-а.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень похожая тема вот, но с маленьким массивом да, понятно, а с моей адской структурой, как по мне, не применимо.

Подскажите, как это чудо можно разобрать и получить желаемое?
Спасибо!

Comment: Распарсить один раз, положить данные в более подходящее для этого хранилище (да хоть sqlite), забыть про JSON.

Comment: Данные в JSON-е меняются и парсить нужно будет в приложении раз в какой-то период, поэтому ваш вариант не подходит ((

Comment: Используйте SAX-style парсер на ходу оставляя только нужные данные.

Comment: Вообще структура JSON очень похожа на выгрузку из какой-нибудь БД. Таблица на 13 столбцов и 13670 строк

Comment: Возможно, но это получено именно через API пост-запросом

Comment: Пошел читать про SAX. По результату отпишусь.
Спасибо

Comment: Очень похожий вопрос: [Как прочитать огромный JSON файл в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600164/11515)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен потоковый парсер Json (а ля SAX для XML). Самый простой входит в состав J2EE [JsonParser](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html), работает примерно так (в варианте тупого одноуровневого json потока):

```
final JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(new FileReader("myfile.json"));
String key = null;
String value = null;
while (parser.hasNext()) {
     final Event event = parser.next();
     switch (event) {
        case KEY_NAME:
             key = parser.getString();
             System.out.println(key);
             break;
        case VALUE_STRING:
             String string = parser.getString();
             System.out.println(string);
             break;
        case VALUE_NUMBER:
            BigDecimal number = parser.getBigDecimal();
            System.out.println(number);
            break;
        case VALUE_TRUE:
            System.out.println(true);
            break;
        case VALUE_FALSE:
            System.out.println(false);
            break;
        }
   }
   parser.close();
}
```

Если ваш json имеет уровни вложенности придется слегка попотеть и запоминать статусы вложенности в ветках, типа `if(key.equals("blah-blah"))` - ну в общем это дело техники, если когда-либо писали SAX парсер для XML - это должно быть знакомо.

Отдельно скачать либу [можно здесь](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/) (без J2EE)

Comment: Понял. Буду пробовать. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Разработчики этого странного API поделились куском кода, обрабатывающим сей не менее странный JSON:

`fields  = [r['fields'].index(i) for i in ('151\\210\\3', '151\\210\\206\\3', '151\\31', '210\\77', '210\\78')]`


`values  = [r['values'][i] for i in fields]`

`dataset = [Entry(*v) for v in zip(*values)]`

Подскажите, как эту гармонию перевести на Java - не силен еще на столько, чтобы такое кунг-фу понимать ))))

Comment: Забыл уточнить - этот кусок написан на Python-е

Comment: С получением данных кажется справился. теперь другая беда - кодировка.
Инфа приходит в приложение в таком виде:
`"89571": {
     "Amount": "0", 
     "Keep": "", 
     "Name": "\u0412\u0438\u043d\u043e \u0438\u0433\u0440. \u0411\u0443\u043b\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0438 \u0424\u0440\u0430\u0433\u043e\u043b\u0438\u043d\u043e \u043a\u0440 0,75", 
     "Sum": "0", 
     "Unit": "\u041f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u044f"
},`

т.е. корявая кодировка. 
При запросе я делаю вот так:

`.url(url)
.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
.build();`